# Showing all columns after hide() is not working in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am displaying a table based on the dropdown menu selection. I need to show all the columns when select 'all' is chosen (default) and hide an entire column and some rows based upon a criteria as shown below. The part where I hide the status column and some rows based on the criteria works.

However when I click the 'all' option back on the dropdown, I want the table to show all the contents, but when I do .show(), I only get all the unhidden elements. How do I show all the columns from the dropdown selection?

```
$("#dropdownselect").change(function () {
  var value = this.value;
  if (value == "open") {
    $('.status').hide();
    $('.rows').each(function(index, value) {
      if ($(this).find('.status').text() == "COMPLETE") {
        $(this).hide();
      }
    });
  }

  if (value == "all") {
    $('.status').show();  //does not work
    //or
    $('#table').show(); //does not work
    //or
     $('.rows').show(); $('.status').show() //does not work
  }

});
```

HTML

```
<select id="dropdownselect">
  <option id="all" value="all">All</option>
  <option id="open" value="open">Open</option>
 </select>

<div id="table">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="id_task">ID</th>
        <th class="id_task">Task</th>
        <th class="status">Status</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     {{#.}}
     <tr class="rows">
       <td class="id_task">{{id}}</td>
       <td class="id_task">{{name}}</td>
       <td class="status">{{completed}}</td>
     </tr>
     {{/.}}
   </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show the actual HTML of the `<table>` element, rather than the - angular? - script that creates it? And your posted jQuery attaches a `change` event-handler to the `#list` element, which doesn't seem to be in your posted HTML/script.

Comment: looks like you need `$('.rows').show()` since you're hiding them in your loop

Comment: @DavidThomas sorry, fixed the code for the #list. This is the actual HTML. I am just using handlebars to render the table rows/columns from a JSON obj.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're hiding `.status` and `.rows`, yet you're only showing `.status`. Show the rows as well:

```
$('.rows').show();
```

Comment: I tried all possible combinations, nothing worked. I have a feeling there is some typo somewhere by change event is not getting captured maybe?.

Comment: When I do alert($('#table').html()) I see all the rows,columns but some of them with style=display:none. I need to revert that.

Comment: That's what the code above does - if you specifically want to get rid of inline styling, you can remove the style attribute.

Comment: sorry I take it back. I had a typo. It works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using tables? You should use pure css / divs in my opinion. I would do it like this....

HTML

```
<select id="dropdownselect">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="open">Open</option>
 </select>
<br />
<div style="width:400px;height:auto;display:inline;margin-top:100px;">
    <div class="columns">ID</div>
    <div class="columns">Task</div>
    <div id ="status"class="columns status">Status</div>
    <br />

     <div class="columns">123</div>
    <div class="columns">sample_task</div>
    <div class="columns status">Off</div>
    <br />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.columns {width:150px;height:auto;display:inline-block; }
```

JQUERY

```
$("#dropdownselect").change(function () {
  var value = $('#dropdownselect').val();


  if (value == "open") {
    $('.status').hide();

  }

  if (value == "all") {
    $('.status').show(); 
  }

});
```

[Here is a JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/az5syovu/1/)

Comment: Although this works, I need to show the data in a table format..The rows can be 100+ rows.

Comment: Why would you force divs for tabular data?